# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate & UITableViewDelegate Behavior

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, nsfetchrequest

I have encountered behavior with the FRC and TableView delegates that appears to be inconsistent:

- The initial call to *performFetch* causes the delegate methods to be called as expected. However, if I update the predicate on the FRC's *baseFetch* and then call *performFetch* again, the FRC delegate methods are never called, and the TableView is not updated with new data. To force the table to update and display the new data I am explicitly calling *reloadData*.
- The initial call to *performFetch* correctly builds the TableView's sections. If I change FRCs (the new FCR has a different *fetchRequest* and *sectionNameKeyPath*) and call *performFetch* again, the table and sections update to match the new results, as expected. HOWEVER, if I then go back to the original FRC and call *performFetch*, the sections have the correct names but with the previous FRC's section/row structure. To force the sections to update I am explicitly calling *reloadSectionIndexTitles*.

My feeling is that the delegates should be firing anytime we call *performFetch* if something changes. Explicitly calling *reloadData* and *reloadSectionIndexTitles* seems like an expensive and unnecessary step since that's what the delegates exist for. Am I missing something?

Here's the relevant code:

**NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate**

```
    - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.myTable beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            // Reloading the section inserts a new row and ensures that titles are updated appropriately.
            [self.myTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.myTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.myTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.myTable endUpdates];
}
```

**UITableViewDelegate**

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[currentFCR sections] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[currentFCR sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return section.name;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[currentFCR sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

**Fetching**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)FRC1 {

    if (FRC1 != nil) {
        return FRC1;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[DataProvider instance] getFetch];
    [[DataProvider instance] sortListByFirstSort:request];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

    FRC1 = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                                                   managedObjectContext:[[DataProvider instance] managedObjectContext] 
                                                                     sectionNameKeyPath:@"groupName" 
                                                                              cacheName:nil];
    return FRC1;    

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)FRC2 {

    if (FRC2 != nil) {
        return FRC2;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[DataProvider instance] getFetch];
    [[DataProvider instance] sortListBySecondSort:request]; 


 [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

        FRC2 = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                                       managedObjectContext:[[DataProvider instance] managedObjectContext] 
                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" 
                                                                  cacheName:nil];
        return FRC2;    

    }

    -(void)doFetch{
    NSError *error;
    if (![currentFCR performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
    [self.myTable reloadData];
    [self.myTable reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods controllerWillChangeContent:, etc, are only called if a delegate is set on an NSFetchedResultsController instance.  I don't see any delegates set in your code.

The initial table load (or explicitly calling reloadTable) will cause the UITableViewDataSource methods to be called, fetching data from the currentFCR.  The NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods will not be called if a delegate is not set on an NSFetchedResultsController.

Also, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods are only called if any of the relevant managed objects change (or are added/deleted) within the NSManagedObjectContext.

If you want to replace the NSFetchedResultsController object you will need to reload the table explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the info Chris. I do indeed set the delegate, but didn't show that method. Here it is: 

`-(void)setFCR:(NSFetchedResultsController *)fcr{
 [currentFCR setDelegate:nil];
 currentFCR = fcr;
 [currentFCR setDelegate:self];
}`

So, if I'm understanding you correctly altering the predicate - i.e. a filter on the managed objects - doesn't cause a true change?

Comment: Well, you're not actually changing the predicate or fetchRequest on an existing NSFetchedResultsController instance (which is not allowed). You are replacing your instance with a new one, so you need to tell the table view to refresh.  Might be better to separate into two UITableViewControllers, one for each fetch request?